# creating a cluster from XML file

Tags: java, text-mining, carrot2, lingo

I am working on text analytics. I am using carrot2 api for Java through which I am reading an XML file and trying to generate the cluster. But I am unable to find any simple code snippet for the same. Can someone help me for the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Carrot2 JavaDoc overview](http://download.carrot2.org/stable/javadoc/overview-summary.html#overview_description) has a number of code examples. Furthermore, the [Java API package](http://project.carrot2.org/download-java-api.html) comes with more self-contained Java code examples.